# Стоит ли отключать у браузера кеширование Css стилей?

Tags: javascript, css

Проблема в том, что я сейчас делаю в учебных целях сайт и конечно же я постоянно на сервер загружаю новые css стили и js Скрипты. И мой гугл хром с радостью все это дело кеширует из-за чего при обновлении страницы продолжаются читаться старые стили и скрипты. В интернете везде советуют добавлять GET параметр и динамически формировать путь к файлу css/js. Отсюда вопрос: стоит ли делать это только для разработки (чтобы не мешался кеш) или в продакшен версии тоже? Заранее спасибо

Comment: Не знаю как остальные, а мы в разработке всегда на Disable Cache сидим.

Comment: А в продакшене? Что вы делаете, чтобы у пользователя была всегда свежая версия CSS?

Comment: @CSharpLooser, в продакшене обычно добавляют. При разработке тоже можно — почему нет. Ну и включите: https://i.imgur.com/Zx5MxCf.png

Comment: Да, обычно или добавляют какой-то параметр или настраивают сервер или используют сборщики, которые каждый раз генерирует новое имя файла.